# Don't work authorization in Symfony3 demo

Tags: symfony

I installed symfony demo. Then run php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
PHP 5.6.24

During authorization occurs 302 redirect to the login page and there are no errors. But if you look at the profiler and there will 
_security.last_error Object (Symfony \ Component \ Security \ Core \ Exception \ InvalidCsrfTokenException)

Tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Is the session properly written to the filesystem so that the CSRF validation logic actually compares the token it gave you in the previous request?

Comment: Session parameters is cleared after each request. But this is only in Symfony. Checked the php settings on yii1 –

Comment: Editing config/config.yml and replacing save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%" with save_path: /var/lib/php/sessions fixed my problem.